# Is there a responsive vertical display: flex? (no tables / no JS)

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox, vertical-alignment

Let's say we have two `div` wrappers. Note that each wrapper can change in width and/or height. There are several `div`'s inside this wrapper. The amount of `div`'s can change anywhere from 1 to ~.

I would like to have a horizontal as well as a vertical view.
To get an even horizontal distribution the css property `display: flex;` is used.

I would like to achieve the same effect vertically. `display: table;` very closely resembles what I want to achieve. However, with tables we won't be able to change the height at all.

```
    +-----+-----+-----+            +-----------------+
    |     |     |     |            |                 |
    |     |     |     |            +-----------------+
    |     |     |     |            |                 |
    |     |     |     |            +-----------------+
    |     |     |     |            |                 |
    +-----+-----+-----+            +-----------------+
       display: flex;                 ??????: ????;
```

Consider [this pen](http://codepen.io/finnvoigtlaender/pen/bgPmQe?editors=1100) as a template.

Comment: just change the flex direction - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEQwrb?editors=1100

Comment: @Pete Omg, I didn't know that tag existed. Thanks alot!

Comment: You're welcome - this is a very useful flex playground: http://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-direction` to change the way the flexboxes are displayed.
Values it can take: `row` | `row-reverse` | `column` | `column-reverse`. Default is row.

```css
.flexible {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexible">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Check out [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to help you with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

With the property `flex-direction: column`, you can change the direction of the alignment.

I would recommend this web-site : http://flexbox.help/ . It describe and allow to test all the property for the flexboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You an use `flex-wrap`..

```
.wrapper-h {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNVypq